# Fallback console after Microsoft Access Token Request Error - 400 Bad Request

Tags: reactjs, authentication

The problem is I cannot get the console if the the Microsoft Access Token request is invalid.

My plan is to get the error using `console.log(error)` inside of my `try catch` block but there's no showing in console.

Here's the code I am trying:

```
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const { getUserInfo } = useUserProviderState();

  const fetchingQueriesCount = useIsFetching();
  const { setLoadingByQueryCount } = useLoadingByQueryCount();
  const [userAccount, setUserAccount] = useState(null);
  const { application } = useContext(ApplicationContext);
  const setLoading = useLoading();
  const {
    data: userSummary,
    isLoading: isLoadingUserSummary,
    error: errorSummary
  } = useUserSummary(userAccount ? userAccount.localAccountId : undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoadingByQueryCount(fetchingQueriesCount);
  }, [fetchingQueriesCount])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!errorSummary) console.log({errorSummary})
  }, [errorSummary]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const GetAccessToken = async () => {
      try {
        const request = { scopes: graphScopes, account: accounts[0] };
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken(instance, request);
        return accessToken ? accessToken : null;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error request: ", error) // Here's the console
      }
    };
    try {
      let provider = new SimpleProvider(GetAccessToken, Login, Logout);
      Providers.globalProvider = provider;
      provider.login();

      appInsights.clearAuthenticatedUserContext();
      if (authenticated()) {
        const account = getAccount();
        setLoading(true);
        appInsights.context.user.id = account.idTokenClaims.oid;
        appInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext(account.username); 
        setUserAccount(account);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error provider: ", error) //Here's the console
    }
  }, []);
```